# Page break after \maketitle

Tags: page-breaking, titles

Hi I have some problem again with my first page, this is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{balalla}
\author{someone}

\begin{document}

\centering \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{logo_inria}
\nopagebreak
\maketitle


\end{document}
```

Can someone tell me how to avoid the page break?

Answer (score 11):

You should rather use

```
\begingroup
{\centering \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{logo_inria}\par}
\let\newpage\relax%
\maketitle
\endgroup
```

which locally changes the definition of `\newpage` - executed by `\maketitle` to start at fresh on a clean page - to a no-op.

Comment: +1 Using `tufte-handout`, the [accepted answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134902/14210) centres my title (though not my logo) even when removing the `center` environment around the `\includegraphics` statement, this answer just works. Apart from the centering issue though, both work equally fine with declaring the logo as a `marginfigure` :)

Answer (score 6):

You can incorporate the image into the title by the »[titling](http://ctan.org/pkg/titling)« package.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}   % drop `demo` option in actual document!
\usepackage{titling}

\title{Document Title with incorporated Image}
\author{JaCkO91}

\setlength{\droptitle}{-60pt}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{%
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{logo_inria}
  \end{center}%
}

\begin{document}
 \maketitle
\end{document}
```

---

[image]